# Oauth 604 Graph API error for non-indexable column, even though column is indexable

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql, oauth-2.0, facebook-oauth

Using the Graph API Explorer app, I attempt the following query:
https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer?method=GET&path=fql%3Fq%3DSELECT%20uid%20FROM%20page_fan%20WHERE%20page_id%3D'123412341234'

(fake id above, though I used a real id in my query)

An error is noting:
Your statement is not indexable. The WHERE clause must contain an indexable column. Such columns are marked with * in the tables linked from http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql

However, the uid field in the page_fan table does have an asterisk next to it, indicating it's an indexable column.

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1):

@Lucas Dickey :  I faceed the same problem with you before.
Even the columns in **WHERE** is index-able (marked *), but failed with error like this :

```
{
"error": {
   "message": "Your statement is not indexable. The WHERE clause must contain an indexable   column. Such columns are marked with * in the tables linked from http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql ", 
   "type": "NoIndexFunctionException", 
   "code": 604
 }
}
```

I think this is an "bug" of Graph API Explorer.
But, everything's OK when I copied and run in browser ( add query **access_token** as well), like this :

```
https://graph.facebook.com/fql?q=SELECT+uid+FROM+page_fan+WHERE+page_id=153453&access_token=CAACEdEose0cBANNkxdpIUuuhPXgbS0M6Tpt0GYgL4Q1p2OgwicLHEzCp7EPPVCB4zMqZA1LvWFyEr9aBhysXS13MYy3ZAZAihO0KvM07KWt8dcDqWry2mdTwhHe1yChDcWMQ54UtKCSEQOrTQuIkWcOjBpswiLhQkDWIHd7PnMvsc0mhI8fLsEz7pylxcXGT
```

Hope it works.

Answer (score 0):

The page_id column in your WHERE clause is not indexed (and does not have a * next to it).
http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/page_fan/

Answer (score 0):

According to the index information for page_fan on @Jaokim's link, the page_id is partially indexed, and needs to be used in conjunction with the uid column for a complete index. You might try it with the uid field, or try to get the list of user id's from another query.

From https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/page_fan/:

> This field is partially indexable and must be used in conjunction with the following fields: uid.

Answer (score -1):

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/page_admin/

I think it is more effective for you to make a query from facebook page.